# How to draw GL premitives behind GameObject in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opengl

I have a question that I can't find in a documentation.
I use GL premitives to draw grid. But I can't understand how to push it behind gameObjects. 
Now grid is drawing on main Camera in OnRenderObject, and as result I see grid in front of gameObjects. If I draw it in Update or LateUpdate the grid is visible only in Scene mode. 
So, please, tell me what options do I have?

Comment: It should be possible to do. Check Draco18's answer. If that did not help then post the current code you are using to draw the grids

Answer (score 1):

## Looking over [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)...

I see...

- **OnPreRender** - OnPreRender is called before a camera starts rendering the scene.
- **OnWillRenderObject** - OnWillRenderObject is called for each camera if the object is visible and not a UI element.

Both of these fire before anything renders. Whereas the method you're using now has this description:

> OnRenderObject is called **after** camera has rendered the scene.

Comment: Thank you for response. 
But unfortunately it didn't help me. :(
I think that when I call my draw procedures from OnPreRender or OnWillRenderObject it draws lines even before skybox. Maybe it needs to draw lines after skybox but before gameObjects. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @HedgehogNSK I've worked very little with the OpenGL commands available, and I was using them to draw *on top* of everything, so I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: thanks for helping anyway. 
I found the solution to render gameObjects with second camera after I render grid lines with main camera. But I'm thinking about correctness and perfomence of this choice.

Comment: @HedgehogNSK Actually, that makes a fair bit of sense.